# Parsing a string with Jquery or Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do i pull out the 30 or the 55 basically the number before the last number

```
http://something.com:9090/general/35/30/205
http://something.com:9090/general/3/55/27
http://something.com:9090/general/36/30/277
```

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_regexp.asp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use regular expressions for this.  As a brief example, here you need to do the following:

```
var url = "http://something.com:9090/general/35/30/205";
var category = url.match(/(\d+)\/\d+$/)[1];
```

To parse the regular expression:

- `/` start the regular expression
- `(\d+)` create a group that you want to find the value of later. This group must contain 1 or more number characters
- `\/` next must come a forward slash. The backslash "escapes" the forward slash -- otherwise it would end the regular expression
- `\d+` next must come 1 or more number characters
- `$` this must be the end of the string
- `/` end the regular expression.

The `match` function returns an array of items that we selected -- here, just `(\d+)`.  The `[1]` means "get the first match", which will be `30` in the above string.

Comment: Ah yes, the ol' t-shirt before the t-shirt regex

Comment: @zincorp I think I'm missing something.

Comment: If you have a problem, and you decide to solve that problem with regex, you now have two problems

Comment: This is the most concise solution. Perhaps regex is overkill for this but if you understand it then it does its job just fine.

Comment: @Mike Ruhlin I looked at the solution you give before posting this, and [it seemed to perform better](http://jsperf.com/split-vs-regex).  It seems that the performance advantage depends on the browser, which I didn't initially realise.  I disagree that regex is inherently a problem, as you suggest.

Comment: If you're doing so many string splits inside a web page that those performance gains are tangible, you have at least 3 problems now...

Answer (score 2):

```
var url = "http://something.com:9090/general/35/30/205";
var splits = url.split('/');
return splits[splits.length - 2];
```

This will screw up if your url looks like:
"http://something.com:9090/general/35/30/205/"
but you could always trim off the trailing slashes beforehand.

Answer (score 1):

```
var s = "http://something.com:9090/general/35/30/205";
s.substr(s.lastIndexOf('/') - 2,2);
```

Comment: This will work as long as the number has precisely two digits. `/3/205` and `/300/205` would both give the wrong result.

Comment: @lonesomeday yes you're right ! your answer should do the job. Have a nice Day !

Answer (score 0):

```
var parts = url.split('/');

var i = parts.length, num;
while (--i)  
  if (!isNaN(parts[i]) && !isNaN(parts[i+1])) {
    num = parts[i];
    break;
  }
```

Without regex, and somewhat like Mike Ruhlin's solution, but more specific to the "number before the last number" part of your question.